# Data Undifined Variable Error from View to PDF

Tags: php, database, laravel

Hello i'm trying to save an html page into pdf
this page have some data that I get from my DB
I have tryed a lot but nothing worked for me
I just want to send my data to this view so i can get my pdf i don't care about showing the view or no

my routes :

```
Route::get('/confirmation','VerificationsController@afficherconfirmer');
  Route::get('/confirmer','VerificationsController@confirmer');
```

My functions:

```
public function afficherconfirmer(){
    $professor = Auth::user();
    $exams = $professor->exams;
    $verifications = Verification::with('exam')->whereIn('exam_id', $exams->pluck('id') )->where([
    ['confirmation', 'non'],
    ['modifier', 'oui'],
    ])->get();

    return view('confirmations.confirmer',compact('verifications','professor'));

  }
  public function confirmer(){
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('confirmations.confirmer');
    return $pdf->download('confirmation_changement_notes.pdf');
  }
```

Even with this I get the error undifined variables

Any idea how can I passe the data to my view without this first route so i can get my pdf with the data ?
Can I create something like this?

```
public function confirmer(){
    View::composer('confirmations.confirmer', function ($view) {
      $professor = Auth::user();
      $exams = $professor->exams;
      $verifications = Verification::with('exam')->whereIn('exam_id', $exams->pluck('id') )->where([
      ['confirmation', 'non'],
      ['modifier', 'oui'],
      ])->get();
  });
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('confirmations.confirmer');
    return $pdf->download('confirmation_changement_notes.pdf');
  }

  }
```

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: What are those undefined variables?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that you want to call only the confirmer route then

```
   public function confirmer(){
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('confirmations.confirmer');
    $dataPDF = $pdf->download('confirmation_changement_notes.pdf');
    $this->afficherconfirmer($dataPDF) //Returns the data to the afficherconfirmer
  }
```

You will be passing the data to the afficherconfirmer, $dataPDF is my assumed data that you passed from confirmer()

```
public function afficherconfirmer($dataPDF){
    $professor = Auth::user();
    $exams = $professor->exams;
    $verifications = Verification::with('exam')->whereIn('exam_id', $exams->pluck('id') )->where([
    ['confirmation', 'non'],
    ['modifier', 'oui'],
    ])->get();

    return view('confirmations.confirmer',compact('verifications','professor'));

  }
```

You can now call both controllers in one single route by calling the function within the controller